# Does $AB = I_m$ imply $n\geq m$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $A ∈ M_{m×n}(F)$ and $B ∈ M_{n×m}(F)$ be two matrices such that $AB = I_m$. What should I be thinking to prove that $n ≥ m$?

Comment: rank = rowrank = column rank

Comment: $m=\mbox{rank} AB \leq \mbox{rank} B \leq n$.

Comment: @julien So $rank(AB)=rank(I_m)$?

Comment: Well, $AB=I_m$ so $\mbox{rank}(AB)=\mbox{rank}(I_m)$.

Answer (score 3):

Cultural remark from the (abstract-algebra) side: I think that this relies heavily on the matrix entries being commutative.  There are some shocking counterexamples with noncommutative rings where all intuition about dimension goes out the window.

Comment: I'm ready to bet $F$ stands for field.

Comment: @julien: do the newer books in French still use "corps commmutatif"?

Comment: He, he. Good point. Yes, I guess so. But it's been a long time since I have bought a math book in French, actually.

Comment: Do you actually have a concrete counterexample in this particular case?

Comment: In my notes, "somewhere".  It would take time to excavate.

Comment: Ok, don't worry then.

Comment: @julien I would like a copy of that counterexample reference, please. Could you manage?

Comment: @BarisaBarukh, if you post a question on a subject like "nonintuitive rank/dimension behavior of matrices over noncommutative rings" there are many examples and several people here who can list some immediately.

Comment: @BarisaBarukh I was asking for such a counterexample. So I don't know. Like zyx, I suggest you ask a separate question.

Comment: @Barisa, I think you can build counterexamples in the ring of Hamiltonian quaternions starting from the observation that the vectors $(1,i)$ and $(j,k)=(1,i)j$ are obviously linearly dependent as vectors of the *right* $\mathbb{H}$-module $\mathbb{H}^2$, but they are linearly *independent* as vectors of the *left* $\mathbb{H}$-module $\mathbb{H}^2$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I'd like to see a detailed description of that.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $n<m$. Pad $A$ and $B$ with zeroes to turn them into square matrices $A', B'$. What is the product $A'B'$? What if you take $\det$ of both sides?